# Proving using laws of logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Show that $(\lnot p\lor ¬q)\to\lnot q ~\equiv~ p\lor\lnot q$ using laws of logic. So

$~~~~~( ¬p\lor\lnot q) \to\lnot q 
\\\equiv~\lnot(\lnot p\lor \lnot q)\lor q
\\\equiv~p\land q\lor q
\\\equiv~p\land q$

Then how am I supposed to prove that is equivalent to $p\lor\lnot q$ ?

Comment: First equiv wrong : $(¬p∨¬q) →¬q ≡¬(¬p∨¬q)∨¬q≡(p∧q)∨¬q$

Comment: Try to use MathJax $\neg$=\neg, $\vee$=\vee, $\rightarrow$=\rightarrow, $\equiv$=\equiv, $\wedge$=\wedge.

Comment: Or (to make it harder to forget which is which) their synonyms `\land`, `\lor`, and `\lnot`. (Sadly, `\lif` and `\lequiv` don't exist.)

Comment: Why is the first equiv wrong?

Comment: Because the equivalence of $X\to\neg q$ is $\neg X\vee\neg q$.  Also you added a negation to $p$ in $(p\lor\neq q)$ for no reason.

Comment: Consider that the contrapositive of $(\lnot p\lor \lnot q)\rightarrow \lnot q$ is $q\rightarrow \lnot(\lnot p\lor \lnot q)$, and $\lnot(\lnot p\lor \lnot q)\equiv p\land q$. Therefore, $q\rightarrow p\land q$, so $q\rightarrow p$. The contrapositive of this is $\lnot p\rightarrow \lnot q$. Note that $p\lor \lnot p$, so since $\lnot p\rightarrow \lnot q$, $p\lor \lnot q$.

Comment: @MichaelLee I think you want \neg, not \not.

Comment: Figured that out. Thanks!

Comment: Common typos. $~$ `\neg` is negation ($\neg$), but mistyping the `g` as `q` give not equal `\neq` ($\neq$). $~$  `\lnot` also gives logical not  ($\lnot$). $~$ Forgetting the `l` renders it into a cancel ($\not$ `\not`).  I hate it when that happens, but it still does.

Answer (score 1):

The first equivalence should be: $~(p\lor\lnot q)\to \lnot q ~~\equiv~~ \lnot(p\lor\lnot q)\lor\lnot q$

Then deMorgan's Law makes this $~~\equiv~~ (\lnot p\land q)\lor\lnot q$

From here just apply distribution, complementation, and identity laws.

$$\therefore~~(p\lor\lnot q)\to \lnot q ~~\equiv~~ (\lnot p\lor\lnot q)$$